# List attributes values of a class

Tags: python-3.x

How can I create dynamically a list that contains the value of all the attribute of a class using python 3.7?

```
class Toolchain:
    VS2008 = 'VS2008'
    VS2015 = 'VS2015'
    VS2017 = 'VS2017'
    VS2017_08 = 'VS2017-08'
    GCC = 'gcc'
    CLANG = 'clang'

    # LIST should contains: ['VS2008', 'VS2015', 'VS2017', 'VS2017-08', 'gcc', 'clang']
```

I tried using list comprehensions, like this:

```
LIST = [eval(param) for param in dir() if not param.startswith('_')]
```

but I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'CLANG' is not defined
```

Comment: There is `vars(Toolchain).values()` but it has some extra crap in it too. Look at [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) stdlib instead.

Comment: You are looking for `vars` which just calls the `.__dict__` of the object, in this class a class, so you get all of the class attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, you can access class attributes via `__dict__` or the more readable `vars()` function. Knowing that these return a dictionary, you can just use `items()` for your list comprehension.

```
LIST = [val for key, val in vars(Toolchain).items() if not key.startswith('_')]
```

This should give you the following output:

```
['VS2008', 'VS2015', 'VS2017', 'VS2017-08', 'gcc', 'clang']
```